# crazy hibernate criteria with extra condition on join?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have 2 entities that are related :

```
@Entity
public class Base_Group implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Set<Base_Role> roles = new HashSet<Base_Role>(0); 
    ...

@Entity
public class Base_Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Base_Group> groups = new HashSet<Base_Group>(0); 
    ...
```

and I want to fetch data using this criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = hem.getSession().createCriteria(Base_Group, "g");
criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                .add( Projections.property("g.id"), "id" )
                .add( Projections.property("g.name"), "name" )
                .add( Projections.property("roles.id"), "roleId" ) )
            .createAlias("g.roles", "roles", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("roles.id", roleId))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RoleGroups.class));
```

but criteria made bad query like this :

```
select this_.id as y0_, this_.name as y1_, roles1_.id as y4_ from Base_Group this_ 
left outer join Base_Role_Base_Group roles3_ on this_.id=roles3_.groups_id and ( roles1_.id=? ) 
left outer join Base_Role roles1_ on roles3_.roles_id=roles1_.id and ( roles1_.id=? )
```

while had bad extra condition in first join. any idea to solve this criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did it here:

```
.createAlias("g.roles", "roles", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("roles.id", roleId))
```

Use:

```
...
.createAlias("g.roles", "roles", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RoleGroups.class))
.add(Restrictions.eq("roles.id", roleId));
```

But, I recomend do it with HQL. Thats a static query with a single restriction.

Comment: If I do what you said I lose records which roles.id is not equal with  roleId while I want them with null as roleId (left join instead inner join), in addition in this case my criteria is dynamic but I brief its conditions.

Comment: Its true... I think thats a Hibernate bug.